# How to get the value of n-th item in a JSON list (using JQuery)?

Tags: jquery, json, forms

How do I retrieve the *n*-th value in a JSON file (and maybe it's children, too)?

For example, I have a collection of courses and associated events formatted in JSON, which I'm using to populate a couple of select lists, e.g:

```
// extract from courselist.php
[{
    "optionValue": "Getting Research into Practice",
    "events": [
        {"date": "29 October"}
    ] 
},
{
    "optionValue": "Human Resources for Managers",
    "events": [
        {"date": "September 1"},
        {"date": "November 2"}
    ]
}]
```

I'm doing this to create the form from that JSON:

```
$(function(){
$("select#coursetype").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("courselist.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(data){
        var options = ''; //item in select list
        options += '<option value=""></option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + [i] + '">' + data[i].optionValue + '</option>';  
            $("#courselist").html(options);
            $('#courselist option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        };
    })
})  
});
```

..which outputs HTML along the lines of:

```
<select id="coursetype" name="coursetype">
    <option value="0">Getting Research into Practice</option>
    <option value="1">Human Resources for Managers</option>
</select>
```

Say, the user selects 'Human Resources for Managers' (value="1"), and $_POSTs the form, how can I later retrieve that course name and it's event info from the POST value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you still have the JSON object available, you can just [feed the posted value back](http://jsfiddle.net/85szf/) into it as an index:

```
var courseName = data[postValue].optionValue;
var courseEvents = data[postValue].events;
for(theDate in courseEvents){
    // do something with the date
}
```